# I/O priority per LVM volume (cgroups)

Tags: lvm, io, cgroup

How can I prioritize LVM volumes I/O performance using cgroups?

I know I can use ionice to make changes at the process level but I wish to be able to do this  per LV and not per process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lvm volume is a normal block device, so you can configure various process priorities on lvm volume using cgroup, for more information read this doc https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/blkio-controller.txt

example:

```
  lvdisplay -v /dev/vg00/rootvol | grep "Block device"
  echo "$MAJOR:$MINOR $((1024*250))" > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/blkio.throttle.write_bps_device
```

Comment: Is this device specific ? $major and $minor are for the specific LV I want to tune?

Comment: yes, that's, you need to use the major and minor of the lvm volume

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt

Comment: it did not work to lower the SATA vs SSD copy bottle neck (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306827/30352), but may be I should be using SSD vs SSD instead? in a sense that SATA vs SSD will never cope?

Comment: @AquariusPower I think that you need to check the ioscheduler, this work with cfq.

Comment: Link in answer gives a 404, this is why you should copy parts of it that is relevant.